# Initialize the view controller in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a custom view controller named `CKCalendarViewControllerInternal`.

**CKCalendarViewControllerInternal**

This class is the subclass of `UIViewController`.

**CkCalendarViewController**

I have a custom view controller named **CKCalendarViewController**. It's a subclass of `UINavigationController` as follow:

```
@interface CKCalendarViewController : UINavigationController <CKCalendarViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

This class is initialize with the `CKCalendarViewControllerInternal` as follow:

```
- (id)init
{
    CKCalendarViewControllerInternal *calendarViewController = [CKCalendarViewControllerInternal new];

    self = [super initWithRootViewController:calendarViewController];
}
```

Now, In `AppDelegate` my first view is as follow:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *n1=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    n1.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.viewController, nil];

 self.window.rootViewController=n1;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**CkDemoViewController**

This class is the subclass of `CkCalendarViewController` as follow

```
@interface CKDemoViewController : CKCalendarViewController
```

**ViewController.m**

When i try to push the `CKDemoViewController` on button clicked.

***Error & Question***
It shows me error like

`Exception: Pushing a navigation controller is not supported
Exception: [NSException]:Pushing a navigation controller is not supported
ex.name:'NSInvalidArgumentException'
ex.reason:'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`

**Reason for error**
This is because the `CKCalendarViewController` is the subclass of `UINavigationController`.
If i try to open the modal view, it works perfectly.

**But How can i initialize the `CKCalendarViewController` as shown above with the `CKCalendarViewControllerInternal` class??**

**Thank you,**

**Answer will greatly appreciate**

Comment: why custom view controller subclassed with `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Why are you not doing `[[CKCalendarViewController alloc] init]`?

Comment: @LithuT.V, Thanks for your reply. But this is for calendar demo, i take this project from cocoa control.I don't know much about this. link:[https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbcalendarkit]

Comment: @Wain, Where should I alloc/init it?

Comment: @LithuT.V, Just simple asking, How can i initialize the one viewController with another View Controller without the Nib file.

Comment: @Wain,Just simple asking, How can i initialize the one viewController with another View Controller without the Nib file.

Comment: Perhaps the question is better: why are you doing `UINavigationController *n1=[[UINavigationController alloc]init];` instead of using your custom classes?

Comment: @Wain, because i don't want to show my custom class as a first view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, the simplest "hackish" way to make things work would be making `CKCalendarViewController` derive from `CKCalendarViewControllerInternal`. I am suggesting this because I see that you are trying to use your `CKCalendarViewController` as a normal view controller, so there should be no reason to have it be a navigation controller.

Another possibility would be for you to actually use your `CKCalendarViewController` as a navigation controller by doing this in your app delegate:

```
UINavigationController *n1 = [[CKCalendarViewController alloc]init];
n1.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.viewController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = n1;
```

but this depends on what you are trying to achieve.

More generally, if you are interested in "nesting" controllers within controllers, you should learn about [controller containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html). In controller containment, what you do to add a controller to another one is basically this:

```
[vc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```